# how to switch between views by tap in sencha touch 2.0.0

Tags: sencha-touch-2

i am following sencha touch 2.0.0 MVC architecture. there are a tab panel in my main.js file, and another tab panel (y) as a xtype of my main panel.
now i want to switch tabs of my another panel (y) dynamically at run time.
how can i achieve this .. please reply me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tab panel has a setActiveItem (or something named like that) method. Check the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com)

Comment: thanx for the help, i used setActiveItem() as per my need.
my problem is solved by using navigationView